# python script to open tera term application and get the teraterm output

Tags: python, teraterm

I want to automate the Tera-term application using python script. First of all i am new to python.
I managed to write a python script by which i am able to open the Tera-term with specific port and predefined baud rate and also i can give the key inputs via python.
Now I need to read the output printed in Tera-term using python script.. But i couldn't find a way to do so..
Could you please provide any solution for this.

To open the Tera-term

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\teraterm\\ttermpro.exe",'/C=7','/BAUD=115200'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.